# Only Heading 7, but not Headings 1, 2, or 3 showing in Styles Box on Home Tab in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2003

My styles box in Word is only showing Heading 7, no matter which recent document I open, whereas it should be showing Headings 1, 2, and 3, which are the only ones I'm using. Also expand/collapse not working in the main document, but working in the outline in the side pane. It's doing this in both Word 2003 and Word 2006. I just created a new document from scratch, and the style box is normal, with Headings 1, 2, and 3, and everything normal, I can copy the document into the new file by removing formatting, but then it seems like it removes all my footnotes, even the text. Also documents I had not opened recently are normal, but seem to get corrupted when I click on enable editing (they were created in Google Docs). But when I first converted docs from Google, I don't think there was a problem. I think it's something I did in Word, not sure. The footnotes are so voluminous, it may not be practical to copy and paste each one and redo them all. Any ideas?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are both versions of Word installed on the same computer? Available styles are usually determined by the primary template, normal.dot.

Comment: They are. Maybe I'll try uninstalling one of them at a time when I have time, to see if that makes a difference. It was defaulting to styles 1 and 2 etc., but just the style box was showing only style 7 (of the numbered styles), so I couldn't select styles 1 etc. to expand/collapse, etc. (as I recall).I started a new Word document today, and after I worked on it all day, the screen went dim and it wouldn't accept any inputs.